# How can i print data from table in cpp using sqlite3 db?

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite

I have created a student table in .cpp.

```
static const char student[] = R"sql(
    CREATE TABLE if not exists student(
        id        VARCHAR(44) NOT NULL,
        name       varchar NOT NULL,
    );
)sql";
```

I am adding some data in this table from another class. I know data has been added to this table, but I want to print all value from this table for verification.

then I write this statement,

```
static const char print_student[]="select * from student";
```

how can I print student table' data in CPP? I am using sqlite3 db.

Comment: Databases may have different APIs for the result sets.  Can't help you any further because you have stated which database you are using and what interface (API) you are using.  Please edit your post with the information.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, i am using sqllite, idk which API I AM USING? What do you mean by API?

Comment: I am very bigger for programing.

Comment: You are likely using this: [https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html)

Comment: yeah, i am using SQLLITE